# bind php parameters into mysqli prepared statement from class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm thinking about using a database table prefix with my mysqli queries.
I have:

```
$db_table_prefix = "";
GLOBAL $db_table_prefix;

class test{
    private $table_prefix;
    public function __construct(){
        global $db_table_prefix;
        $this->table_prefix = $db_table_prefix;
   }

   public function test2(){
       $stmt = $db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM {$this->table_prefix}users WHERE name = 'test'");
   }
}
```

How can I use the prefix in the query itself?

Comment: You might prefer to define a [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) instead of using variables, both because there's no risk of it being changed and because you won't need to worry about [scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: how would I insert into sql statement?

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems you ARE using the prefix in the query.

Comment: @Marjeta that's what I want to do but it's not working. If the prefix was "custom_" I would want it to select id from custom_users where ...

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from:

```
   public function test2(){
       $stmt = $db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM {$this->table_prefix}users WHERE name = 'test'");
   }
```

to

```
   public function test2(){
       $sql="SELECT id FROM {$this->table_prefix}users WHERE name = 'test'";
       echo $sql;
       $stmt = $db->mysqli->prepare($sql);
   }
```

Always use it this way: first create the string, then display the string and then do call the database -- then you will know exactly what you are executing.

Whe you are confident that your code works correctly, you can always comment out the echo statement.

How do you call this code?